# Error training transformer with QLoRA and Peft

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

So I am trying to finetuning google Gemma model using Peft and QLoRA. Yesterday I successfully fine-tuned it for 1 epoch just as a test. However, when I opened the notebook today and ran the cell that loads the model I get a huge error:

The code:

```
model_id = "google/gemma-7b"

bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
load_in_4bit=True,
bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16
)

tokenizer = 
AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
model_id, 
quantization_config=bnb_config, 
device_map={0:""})

#model.gradient_checkpointing_enable()

train_dataset, val_dataset, data_collator = load_dataset(train_data_path, val_data_path, tokenizer)
```

The error (shortened):

```
RuntimeError: device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp":50, please report a bug to PyTorch. device=1, num_gpus=

.....

DeferredCudaCallError: CUDA call failed lazily at initialization with error: device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp":50, please report a bug to PyTorch. device=1, num_gpus=
.....

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.integrations.bitsandbytes because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
CUDA call failed lazily at initialization with error: device >= 0 && device < num_gpus INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED at "../aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAContext.cpp":50, please report a bug to PyTorch. device=1, num_gpus=

.....
```

I have shortened the error for it to be more readable. Has anyone experienced something like this? I can't seem to solve it. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you opened the notebook, the RAM memory is reset so it no longer has the CUDA initialization configuration so it triggered the above error. The only way to fix this error is to rerun the entire notebook not just that specific cell